# how ignore duplicate values without consider of their position in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have this table with one column

A:

```
16654,16661

16661,16654

16670,16717

16717,16670
```

I want to have this: (ignore duplicate values without consider of their position)

```
16661,16654

16670,16717
```

is there any math function that operate between two number and have unique result?

actually i have this table ( name:class)

```
id    second_code    have_second_code
1      0             no
2      3             yes
3      2             yes
4      5             yes
5      4             yes
```

when "have_second_code" is "yes"
column second_code have a value!
id is primary

second code is from id column and there is a binary relation between them. now i need this output **2,3 and 4,5**

Comment: You should never store multiple values in one column. You will get in a lot of trouble. Read about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: this is result of another query! i wrote like this for ask a simple problem!

Comment: in PHP put them all inside an array as strings then use array unique

Comment: @BehnooshMoshtagh Then show the other query.

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to find the `DISTINCT` function?

Comment: @BehnooshMoshtagh Please provide sample data that fits together. And the query that produces your first table.

Comment: No more info from your side? Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rowone, rowtwo, rowonemillion FROM yourtable GROUP BY(nodupecolumn)
```

Comment: Can you please provide some explaination on what you're doing?

Comment: Take note that this is, though working in MySQL, not valid (=standard compliant) SQL since `GROUP BY` does not behave that way according to standards

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that your query that produces this one-column-multiple-values-table uses `GROUP_CONCAT()`. In this case you need to do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT whatever_column ORDER BY whatever_column) FROM ...
```

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword two times. In `GROUP_CONCAT()`, so that duplicates are removed from the comma separated values, and one time outside of `GROUP_CONCAT()`, so that duplicate rows are removed. The `ORDER BY` in `GROUP_CONCAT()` is important, otherwise the outer `DISTINCT` won't detect duplicates. Also note, that (outer) `DISTINCT` works on the whole row, not just one column.